# Why is it called "Suggested edits queue is full." once I'm suspended somehow?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, account-suspension

> I once was suspended in Stack Overflow (the time that I'm implying in this question) and I currently am.

I came across my account on Stack Overflow and I want to edit a post. Turns out I was suspended, but for some reason, instead of "Account is suspended.", it was "Suggested edits queue is full.".

I took a look further on the question and asked if one of my friends owned it. Turns out their question has no suggested edits at all.

I also checked if people suggested edits on any of my questions. Turns out there's none.

Is this a bug? Let me know.

Comment: The suggested edits queue can be full even if none of your own posts have pending edits. The queue is currently at 370 so it probably was at 400 or more edits when you tried to edit something. It’s been happening more than usual this year.