# "Suggested edit queue is full" should link to information about reason

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, popups

Here:
[Why is it called "Suggested edits queue is full." once I'm suspended somehow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356446/why-is-it-called-suggested-edits-queue-is-full-once-im-suspended-somehow)
I found a description of what the reason is for the popup tip "Suggested edit queue is full".

[image: Example of "queue is full" PopUp]

I want to request the following feature:

Please add a link in the "Suggested edit queue is full" pop-up message which
will lead users/members to a broader description of the problem and
its causes. Similar as done when trying to comment or vote when one lacks the privileges to do so.

[image: First Example of PopUp message with link do information about]
[image: Second Example of PopUp message with link do information about]

Comment: Tagging this [status-review] because we got quite a few confused users in the last 6-8 weeks. I can only imagine the situation on MSO must be worse. (Only after I did that, I realized I wrote an answer before - I hope the OP can later accept another answer that states the feature request has been implemented.)

Comment: I've converted [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) into an [faq] post. Goal (fingers crossed): link to that post from this error message. cc @Glorfindel

Answer (score 19, accepted):

'Suggested edit queue is full' *always* means there are [too many pending edits in the review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84398/295232). If you encounter this, there's nothing you can do about this (with one minor exception - if you have between 2k and 20k reputation, you can help reviewing suggested edits, which decreases the queue size, in order to suggest an edit to a tag wiki or tag excerpt yourself).

The examples you mention about commenting and voting also provide potentially misleading information in case you're suspended. Your lack of reputation is not the problem, the suspension is. You simply can't expect Stack Exchange to optimize the experience for suspended users.

Also, suspended users should *not* suggest edits, not even when logged out: [Anonymous contribution (without an account) while suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331883/295232) One of the points of the suspension is that you can still use the site, but only in read-only mode, because your 'write' actions have caused trouble in the past.

Comment: I think the OP is not themselves suspended, but instead they found information about what *"suggested edit queue is full"* means at the other question where that author's question **is** suspended. So it seems this OP just wants to link the tooltip that says  "suggested edit queue is full" to a more detailed explanation (that there are too many pending edits in the review queue site-wide)

Comment: Perhaps "Please try again later" can be added. A link isn't necessary IMHO, for background information of less important Stack Exchange functionality you need to search on Meta anyway.

Comment: Yea I agree. The feature request could just be changing the wording. Maybe "too many pending edits in the site-wide review queue".

Comment: As a non English native speaker and beginner SO user, I would also to confirm that all of the above comments on this answer are in line with what I mean.

Comment: I came across the same message brought forward by the OP and had to find this answer with a search engine precisely because of the lack of context. This very experience shows in itself that the OP's point is relevant. I also agree with other remarks that the point of being suspended is not essential. @MichałLipok

Comment: What do you mean by "*between 2k and __20k reputation__*"? You mean people having 20k+ rep can't review suggested edits?

Comment: @RandomPerson people having 20k+ rep don't need the suggested edit queue (for tag wiki/excerpt edits)

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm talking about 20k+ rep users' ability to review other users' (who have less than 2k rep) suggested edits (of posts).

Comment: @RandomPerson that certainly works. I wrote that sentence from the PoV of a user who is encountering the problem of a full suggested edit queue.

Comment: @Glorfindel I feel that sentence needs to be reworded for more clarity.

Comment: @RandomPerson better?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the current message if the system side queue is full or my suggested edit is full.

Answer (score 5):

This change is going live shortly. Instead of "Suggested edit queue is full," users will see:

> There are [too many pending edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/whats-the-fixed-size-of-the-suggested-edit-queue) on $sitename. Please try again later.

The link goes to the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ question explaining why the queue has a size cap, and what that limit is. The site name changes dynamically on each site, but the link will always point to that question on Meta SE.

(I've protected the question on Meta SE for good measure.)

Comment: One downside of this otherwise good change is boosting the amount of lost souls here, people who arrive here from different site, thinking they are still on that other site, and asking their question.

Comment: @Shadow If there are wider concerns about that in the future, I may be able to measure whether this change is the cause. I suspect it won't have a significant impact, if any, but I'm happy to let time prove me wrong :)

Comment: Just double checking that's an absolute link. We didn't test on MSE again and have a [relative link slip through again](/a/382572/1099857)

Comment: @HenryEcker Yep, should be an absolute link. The site name is generated dynamically but the MSE link is just bare text.