# "Suggested edit queue is full" without pending edits?

Tags: bug, questions, suggested-edits

I had this problem for some days that I can't edit any questions or answers anymore.

Every time I click on "Edit" I'm getting "Suggested edit queue is full".

Judging by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360018/suggested-edit-queue-is-full-should-point-to-information-about-reason), it can only mean that that I have too many pending edits, but I can’t seem to find any [on my Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15139141/tolik518?tab=activity).

Could there be another reason? Is this a bug?

Comment: Either logging out and in seems to have fixed it, or a mod unlocked it back again for me?
Nevertheless it works again, thank you :)
Question can be closed. Or is it better to delete it?

Comment: There is a limit on the total number of suggested edits from everybody (500 on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @greg-449 Oh so there can be only 500 edits pending at the same time from all users?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: @Luuklag Ok that wasn't clear to me and is pretty unexpected to be honest, but it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The queue on Stack Overflow is generally close to the limit most of the time.

Comment: And also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284