# Is there a way to get my edited post to be reviewed faster?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When I click on the "Edit" button in a post in stackoverflow.com, I always get a red box saying

> Suggested edit queue is full

[image]

Where can I find my last edited post that is in the queue to be reviewed? Is there a way for my edit to be reviewed faster?

Comment: [Suggested edit queue is full](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125)

Comment: It might be [a particular bad day](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419743/the-edit-queue-is-full-what-can-we-do-with-it) today.

Comment: @VLAZ It's always full. This happened to me day after day when I tried to edit back in July, so eventually I gave up and [left a comment on the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58925279/11343425) instead. This meta post reminded me of it so I went back and try to submit the edit again.... still full.

Comment: Or [this week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419765/suggested-edits-take-way-too-long-to-be-reviewed-due-to-a-change-to-the-top-bar).

Comment: @SurpriseDog I don't get into the Suggested Edit queue as much as I used to but any time I've checked it recently it's been under 400 (349 at the moment). I'm guessing certain times of day are bad. I can make the edit for you unless you'd like to try again first.

Comment: @BSMP Sure, go right ahead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have any pending suggested edits; we can see this [on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16079539/gold79?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). What the message is trying to say is that there is no room for *anybody* to suggest new edits, because there are too many pending ones (and too few reviewers). See also ["Suggested edit queue is full" without pending edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/372134/295232)

> Is there a way to get my edit to be reviewed faster?

In this case it doesn't matter whose edits get reviewed. If you'd ever feel the need to make an 'urgent' edit, e.g. because somebody leaked their password, it's better to flag for moderator attention because that information needs to be redacted anyway. Or leave a comment for the author so that they can change it themselves (though a suggested edit also causes an [inbox notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353/295232)).

Comment: hi @Glorfindel, I've just checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) that there are only 300+ posts in the Suggested Edits queue at this moment, is it correct?

Comment: @Gold79 for me, the number is 491.

Comment: The red message is still present for me, so there is still no room for anybody to suggest new edits when there are only 400+ in queue?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get your edit to be reviewed faster unfortunately, you just have to wait. It usually depends on what site you are on. E.g. if you are on Stack Overflow, then chances are you are going have to wait a while, as there are thousands of edits waiting to be reviewed at any one time. On lower traffic sites your edit may get accepted a lot faster. One thing that always happens on SO, is that *nobody* can suggest anymore edits, which is probably what you are experiencing.

Comment: *thousands of edits* = up to 500. see suggested edit queue size: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84362/why-does-the-suggested-edit-queue-have-a-fixed-size-and-what-is-its-size-on-eac