# Reword the error message for a full suggested edit queue, as many users are getting confused with its current wording

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, wording, error-message

The current message for a full suggested edits queue (where lots of people have suggested edits and the overall queue of pending edits from anyone is full) is:

> Suggested edit queue is full

This doesn't tell anything about the problem. More specifically, we have a lot of complaints from confused users on meta sites (especially [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=edit+queue); here's an [example here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381878/while-editing-questions-in-stack-overflow-i-got-this-error-message-like-queue?noredirect=1)) where users think that the message is personally directed at them, as they've suggested too many pending edits even though they're under their personal limit (five or 20 depending on site lifecycle status). Specifically, the message doesn't mention anything about the queue being site-wide. We have to repeatedly answer this large subset of complaints about the edit queue (or comment and close as duplicate) that the edit queue the error message is stating is site-wide.

I propose that the message be reworded as follows, to prevent meta sites with persistently full edit queues (e.g. Stack Overflow) from being overrun with this subset of complaints:

> Suggesting edits has been temporarily disabled due to the high volume of edits awaiting review. Please try again in a few minutes. [More information](//)

...where that last link goes to a help center page explaining about the site-wide edit queue and how suggesting edits can be temporarily blocked if too many edits are awaiting review. The last sentence also implies that there's nothing for them to do other than wait, and also that the message isn't directed at them personally.

Comment: I've tagged ["Suggested edit queue is full" should point to information about reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360018/295232) as [tag:status-review] today - that should solve it, no?

Comment: @Glorfindel That request as written only asks for a link to be added, and doesn't ask for the message to be reworded. I think it should be reworded, as having the true explanation be behind a link may cause some users to miss it and only a small part of the complaints will be abated. It's better for the message itself to explain something.

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full" is short, simple, and clear, at least to me, even if I try to pretend I'm a totally new user. I know suggested edits go to a queue, and that queue is now full, so that's why I can't suggest a new edit.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard It might be clear to *you*, but the repeated complaints on Meta.SO (see the search page I linked) indicate it's not clear to lots of other people.

Comment: Sorry, link is useless with thousands of results, I'm *not* going to search inside the search results for the relevant questions. You better put a list yourself, of e.g. 5 such questions. But still, it's trivial to search for the editing faq, see what suggested edits are and how they work. Prior research is expected in meta sites as well.

Comment: I like the idea. I would add that there are too many suggested edits from all users to make it more clear without needing to click the link.

Comment: @Ethan I think the current phrasing "high volume" makes this clear. The post notice for comment locks used to say "This post has been locked due to the high volume of off-topic comments generated" before the system was changed to only disable comments with that type of lock and not other things (edits, answers to locked questions, etc.)

Comment: The reason the suggested edit queue is full is that way too many users suggest formatting-only changes, leaving all other problems untouched.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum You inspired me to finally write [a feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381358/give-back-the-ability-to-indicate-that-a-suggested-edit-is-not-helpful-when-impr) I've been thinking of for a while.

Comment: "*users think that the message is personally directed at them, as they've suggested too many pending edits even though they're under their personal limit*" another **very** common misinterpretation of the message is that there is a queue *per post*. The end result is not far off thinking it's a queue *per user* but still - goes to show how unclear the message can be. Is there one queue? One queue per person? One queue per post?