# While editing questions in Stack Overflow I got this error message, like 'Queue is full'

Tags: feature-request, support

While trying to *improve* the closed question on **Stack Overflow** by editing it, it didn't allow me to make an edit. Instead it shows me an error message like this. **Even though I didn't edit more than five today**. And when will I be able to **re-edit** again?

[image: This was the error message I got]

Comment: When the queue's no longer full.

Comment: There is a limit on the total number of pending edits by all users (500 on Stack Overflow)

Comment: How to know the queue is no full?